# Perform selector when ViewController gets shown?

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, uiviewcontroller

I'm loading a view controller like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

It works but when I call it a second time the view is the same (of course). I need to perform a selector after the modal view controller gets visible again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[viewWillAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:) or [viewDidAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:) might work for you.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, I used viewWillAppear and it works, so thank you!